# Display a fixed set of terms at the end of each report created through SQL query

Tags: sql, database

So I have a task to create a report that displays some data, for which I have a working query. The next challenge is that every time I run the query, it should also print certain terms with the report. The terms are in the form of the table itself but I have restricted access to the database. I cannot update the table with new data.

What I want to achieve here is:

```
|-------------|
|Report data  |
|-------------|
|Fixed Set of terms|
|------------------|
```

I am looking for a way to append some text at the end of the table. Not sure how can I do that, hoping for some help.

Comment: `UNION` *(specifically as `UNION ALL`)* is your friend.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  x, y, z
FROM
  foo

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'SOMETHING', 1, 5

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'ANYTHING', 2, 7

ORDER BY
  x, y, z
```

The data types being unioned should match, don't try to union integers with strings, for example.

The `ORDER BY` is applied after the `UNION`s.

`UNION` normally searches for and removes duplicates. Specifying `UNION ALL` avoids that costly overhead.